# Unnecessary line break in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uitextview

I am programmatically writing to a UITextView a comma separated string. 
Example: NSString* str = @"cat,dog,big dog,kitten".

On [textView setText:str]; I get the results as: 
       cat,dog,big
       dog,kitten.

I don't understand why is the space getting converted to a line break. Any idea?

Comment: There is not enough information, provide information about the UITextView and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

the space gets converted to a line break, because the text did not fit into one line. This line break mode cannot be disabled, or changed. But you can rise the width of the textview.

Comment: Well, maybe. It depends on the width and font (especially font size) of the text view, and on the string. The string in the question seems like it should fit just fine at the system font in a text view that spans the screen. If the font's bigger, the view is smaller, or the string is different in just the right way, then you're probably right.

Comment: The text will fit in the text view. That's not the problem. What I noted is the strings that contain space are automatically getting translated to new line when displayed in text view. Is it because I am reading from a sqlite DB.

Comment: char *temp = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:temp];

Comment: no, try "word1 word2 word3 word4". are each word in a new line? i dont believe. the whole teyt does not fit into one line i the text view, tnerefore the textview introducrs line breaks at that positions it believes it is best. this has absolutely nothimg to do with sql lite. try it out, hard code that text i to the textview, it will break too.

Comment: @AlexWien [textView setText:@"cat,dog,eagle,elephant,rat,big dog,small dog"]; This works perfectly and comes in one line of the text view. But when I get the same from the database the space is converted to New Line.

Comment: then check your db string before you add it to the text view! is there already a new line? compare the individial characts

Comment: yes, its just not UITEXTVIEW, even the NSLOG prints the output in a new line whenever a space is encountered in a String. Why is this happening. I tried replacing "\n" with " " and also "\r" with space.

Comment: I also replaced " " with "_". It worked as expected, no unnecessary line breaks instead of space. Then again when I replace "_" with " " it gets displayed as a line break.